# Curl Request Timeout failure

Tags: php, curl

I have the following fatal error when trying to use Curl:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$url = '$url';
$ch = curl_init();
$proxy = "8.8.8.8";
$port = "8080";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, "HTTP");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$headers = array(
  'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36',
  'x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest',
  'vary:Accept-Encoding',
  'x-powered-by:PHP/7.1.0',
  'cf-ray:4b8e31281f84b049-IST',
  'device:d'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36");
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
```

//proxy is an example.

I can't get an error when I'm listing and parsing only one category on the target site, but I'm getting this error when trying to list all categories

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you really working with "8.8.8.8" or is it just an example?

Comment: This is just an example ...

Comment: Just to understand better: do you want to catch the error or just solve a problem? And please can you post a description of the error message?

Comment: In fact, the curl fails, it creates a json file on the server when I run the file.
but this file is missing and I get the following error in browser. ""Request Timeout
This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.""

Comment: so where's the fatal error text? Add it to your post. Where do you see it?